# Retrieving multiple queries from mysql using MySqli_fetch_array()

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, html-table

So basically am retrieving data from mySqli from different tables some have  foreign primary relation but some does not 
What i am doing is getting the data(selected columns) and showing it in one html table 
am doing it something like this

```
while (($ans= mysqli_fetch_array($result))&&($ans1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))&&($ans2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))&&($ans3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3))&&($ans4=mysqli_fetch_array($result4)))
                      {
                        echo  "   <td>".$ans['name']."</td> ";
                        echo  "   <td>".$ans1['id']."</td> ";
                        echo  "   <td>".$ans2['company']."</td> ";
}
```

The problem here is that it is not fetching all the records because of && OPERATOR 
and if i am implementing a separate while loop on every query it is not displaying the html table properly 
Help People

Comment: Can't you use a JOIN instead of multiple queries?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz if there is no foreign key how will i join ?

Comment: UNION if the columns are similar.

Comment: If you can't fetch everything with a join, build lookup tables in PHP first.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL UNION so that you can avoid very long conditions in your queries

Example

```
SELECT City FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT City FROM Suppliers
```

> Note: You cannot union together queries which do not have the same
>   number of columns in the select.

- [SQL UNION DEMO](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Bring the relevant part of the link into your post.

Comment: How can i give the exact code if he's only providing the result queries?

Comment: Pull in the example UNION calls. It doesn't have to be OP's queries - but it should be enough that someone could still use your answer even if the link turns into a 404. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers